# Loop through model list in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two classes: Person and account. Im working in asp net.

This is my controller:

```
        public List<Person> GetPeople()
        {
        using (var db = new PeopleContext())
        {
            return db.People.ToList();
        }
        }
```

Person has the following attributes:

```
    public class Person
    {
    public int PersonId{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public List<Accounts> Accounts{ get; set; }
    }
```

Account class contains the following attributes:

```
    public class Account
    {
    public int AccoundId{ get; set; }

    public string AccountName{ get; set; }

    public Person Person{ get; set; }
    }
```

This is in my view

```
    function getQuestions() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Person',
        type: 'GET',
        //dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, p) {
        string += '<h1>Name: '+p.Name+'</h1>';
        $.each(p.Accounts, function (j, a) {
            string += '<p>'+a.AccountName+'</p>';
        });
    });
   },
 });
```

How do i loop through account list in javascript and display it in my view? I have been trying to do this, but the list returns null. When i try to console log data it displays Accounts as null. How do i fix this?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! It seems to me that you're missing an `id` or some unique identifier from the ajax request. You're requesting `/api/Person`; if you just put that in the url bar of your browser, does the data you want come back? Depending on your backend I expect you'll need to either replace the `url` with `/api/Person/*persons-id*/` or `/api/Person/?id=*persons-id*`, or else add a `data` element to the ajax request.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but I want to retrieve all people stored in my database and all accounts belonging to that person. Do I still need to specify an id? p.Accounts in my foreach loop still returns null though.

Comment: Ah you're right, in that case you don't need to specify an id. I still recommend accessing that endpoint and making sure it returns the JSON data you're expecting. Perhaps editing your question to include that response would help.

Comment: I know that json returns an object of type person with the correct attributes, but accounts (the list defined in the class) returns null.

Comment: Are you saying that `accounts` is null based on inspecting the response in the network panel, or loading the endpoint in a browser window, or just based on the javascript code you wrote? Because if it's either of the first two, then that indicates that the problem is with the backend configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to show your /api/Faq webservice response.

I would also suggest opening F12 developer tools and putting the word debugger in after you get the name:

```
string += '<h1>Name: '+p.Name+'</h1>';
debugger;
```

Then you can look at the p.Accounts object and see what it is.

If you Accounts object is empty you may need to add to your Person object's constructor:

```
public Person()
        {
            Accounts= new HashSet<Account>();
        }
```

Comment: I am using code first migrations to seed my database and I know that both the account and person table is filled up.

Comment: Please 1) put that url in your browser and show the response and 2) break point in your javascript using debugger;